# OpenCV: Recognizing the Orientation of a Cube in a 2D Image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I'm looking forward to developing a Rubik's Cube solver (just for fun). For this, the user would take a picture of the cube in a way that three sides of it are visible, like in this picture:

`cubeA.jpg`:

[image]

It can be safely assumed that the cube is covering most of the picture. Now, what I would like to do is detect the exact orientation of the cube. That is, I am interesting in detecting these seven points:

`cubeB.jpg`:

[image]

From this, I would be able to split each of the three faces into 3x3 grid and detect the colors (for which I have already written the code and which works quite well).

Now, I have made a few attempts to solve this problem using corner detection and contour extraction in OpenCV. None of them have been satisfactory, however. Another way of looking at this problem would be to recognize each of the 27 little, so-called “facelets”, and detect the orientation using those. But I'm not sure if that's the right approach either.

How would you go about solving this problem using OpenCV?

Comment: I would try the facelets way or using lineSegmentDetector or thresholding be black lines. All of these approaches look promising to me.

Comment: If you know which colors to expect, then you can try getting those directly and the corners of each color patch would give you the facelets. You then are looking to find 3 different planes (defined by their normals) from these facelet points. Can can get the best-fit plane by looking at the covariance of a set of points.

Comment: @Micka is right, his suggestion seems fine but requires some necessities. Color thresholding is easy to affect by background, shadows, similar target colors in other objects etc.